# C# only runs main() class

Tags: c#, program-entry-point

```
namespace ConsoleApp5
{
class Program
{
    private static MySqlConnection connection;
    private static string server;
    private static string database;
    private static string uid;
    private static string password;


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        server = "localhost";
        database = "database";
        uid = "domica";
        password = "domica";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
    }
    public static void Insert()
    {
        Console.Write("Ukucaj nesto:");
        var kucaj = Console.ReadLine();
        string query = "INSERT INTO table1 (Ci) VALUES (@tt);";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tt", kucaj);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

  }
}
```

That is my code, and I have a simple question about it. That code doesn't work. The Main() part works, yet the Insert() class will never run. If I were to place all the content in the Main() class it would all work, yet I do not want that. I tried switching it to build as a class library, not a console application and I just get an error saying thats not possible. Thanks

Comment: You should call Insert() from main() method

Comment: You might be thinking c# is procedural in that it will run each method in turn? That's not how it works. Main is called automatically, everything else must be called explicitly.

Comment: FYI `Main` and `Insert` are methods.  The only class you have there is `Program`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the Insert() method inside the Main method.

```
namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        private static MySqlConnection connection;
        private static string server;
        private static string database;
        private static string uid;
        private static string password;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            server = "localhost";
            database = "database";
            uid = "domica";
            password = "domica";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
            database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();

            Insert();
        }
        public static void Insert()
        {
            Console.Write("Ukucaj nesto:");
            var kucaj = Console.ReadLine();
            string query = "INSERT INTO table1 (Ci) VALUES (@tt);";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tt", kucaj);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think it's time for some explanations. First of all, some terminology. `Main` and `Insert` are called functions or methods. The only class in your program is `Program`.

#### What are functions?

Functions are (relatively) small chunks of code which are used for a better organisation of your program. They can be reused for when you need to do the same action (or very similar actions) repeatedely. Their actions can be slightly changed and customized using parameters to fit a specific need. Every function must be called (invoked) in order for it to run. `Main` is also a method.

#### Why does Main run without invoking it?

`Main` is called the entry point of your program because it is the only function that is automatically invoked by the program. Inside `Main` you can call other functions that you have defined.

#### Where can I call functions?

You can call a function inside another function. You can even call a function inside itself (procedure called recursivity), just be sure to create an exit condition so that you won't have an infinite loop.

#### *Can* I invoke `Main`?

Of course. But be aware that that means a reexecution of it.

#### *Should* I invoke `Main`?

This may be a discussion subject. From my point of view, you should never invoke `Main`, because it is very dangerous. You can very easily create an infinite loop and it's hard to avoid that. Moreover, it doesn't really give you a great advantage. To be honest, I have never seen a program that reinvokes `Main`.

Hope you understand now and you can ask more helpful question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Every and new function must be called every single time. Call `Insert()` after `connection.Open();` in your `private static void Main(string[] args) { ... }` function.

Good luck